# How to save tabs in a Chrome extension when closing a window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way in a Chrome extension to access the `chrome.tabs` API *before* a window is closed?

I'm working on an extension that moves any pinned tabs to a different window when the window is closed. However, the `chrome.windows.onRemoved()` event listener only fires once the window and all its tabs are closed.

I'm OK with a hacky substitute, since (for now) this extension is just for my personal use.

Answer (score 0):

Try going from the other direction - save each tab when it's created.

This way, you'll always be synced with the last tabs, before "chrome.windows.onRemoved()" is initiated.

Implementation:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener( function(tab) { 
    // add tab to your [tabs list]
} ); 

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener( function(tab) { 
    // remove tab from your [tabs list]
} );
```

Comment: I don't feel that this solves the issue, however: I still need to detect when the window closes and intervene. Namely, both closing the window and closing a pinned tab will fire `tabs.onRemoved()`, but I'm trying to interpret the former as a reason to save the pinned tabs. And I think both eventlisteners fire _after_ the tab is closed.